# Identifying Row Index Number on the Bases of Max Value of Other Column within Group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, row-number

```
 G= c("P52" ,"P52","P66 - PARK II","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P82 V3","P82 V3","P82 V3","P52","P52","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P82 V3","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P82 V3","P82 V3"        ,"P88","P88","P88","P52","P82 V3","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P82 V3","P52","P88","P88","P52" ,"P88","P82 V3","P88","P82 V3","P82 V3","P82 V3","P88","P88","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P88","P66 - PARK II" ,"P88"           ,"P52","P52","P52","P52","P52","P52","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II","P88","P82 V3","P82 V3","P88","P88","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P52","P52","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II","P66 - PARK II" ,"P82 V3","P66 - PARK II" ,"P82 V3","P88","P82 V3","P88","P88","P66 - PARK II","P82 V3","P82 V3" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P82 V3","P88","P88","P82 V3","P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P88"           ,"P66 - PARK II" ,"P66 - PARK II","P66 - PARK II" )
GA = runif(100, min=20, max=50)
GL = runif(100, min=20, max=50)

df=data.frame(G=G,GA=GA,GL=GL)
df$Sq <- seq(1:nrow(df))
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
by_G<- group_by(df,G)
fg1 <- summarise(by_G,
                 Row_Index1=row_number(which.max(GA)),
                 Row_Index2=row_number(which.max(GL)),
                 n=n())
```

Above is the reproducible Code , I am trying to extract the row id Number where Column `GA` has Max value within Group.

Comment: Since `GA` is a grouping variable, I don't understand why you want to find its maximum within groups. In each group, `GA` is a constant.

Comment: I agree with Sven, normally you would do `fg1 %>% slice(which.max(GA))`, but in this case it will just give you the first row in each group since you are grouping by `GA`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein  My Bad  Wrong Data Uploaded , now the data is as per the problem statement , Thank you for correcting me sir

Comment: @Axeman I tried the same Code of `which.max` here i don't want the Fist Row i want the row Number where the GL has max value within Group of G

Comment: Can you provide a table to show the actual values you're trying to get? It's not very clear from the description.

Comment: @Z.Lin required is  `row id` from where `Max_val(GA)` is found But it has to be within group_by of `G`.I guess i am able to explain now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Sq refers to row ID in your dataset, the following will give the row ID with the largest GA within each group G:

```
by_G %>% arrange(desc(GA)) %>% summarise(Sq = first(Sq))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
              G   Sq
         <fctr> <int>
1           P52    46
2 P66 - PARK II    13
3        P82 V3    90
4           P88    55
```